# Azure - Schedule SQL Job

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-job

I'm in the process of creating a small Azure site consisting of the following

- Website
- SQL Database

The website supports user accounts and licensing. I plan on handling the licensing checks via a scheduled SQL service (Much like a SQL agent in SQL Server) once a day.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Azure SQL Database (which I assume you are), then you don't have the SQL Server Agent.

You do however have 2 possible options for your needs:

1. Using [**Azure Automation**](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/automation/), you can use PowerShell to do your scheduled tasks. More info and a sample [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/). Azure Automation is the surrogate for the SQL Agent if you ask me.
2. The other option is [**Azure WebJobs**](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/automation/). I think this is the way to go, as you are already using Azure WebSites and this comes as a feature of it. Scott Hanselman has an excellent [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) about it.